# I can't find what I did wrong

Tags: programming

```cpp
int lightPin = 13;
int buttonPin = 2

void setup() {
  pinMode(lightPin, OUTPUT); //red
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int buttonValue = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonValue == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }  //red
  
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);//red
}  //red
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error message?  Please provide more information.  Also, please edit your question and use the formatting tools to format the code as code.

Comment: why do you think that you did something wrong?

Comment: What is going wrong? Only thing I can see is that your LED will only light for a very brief period when you press the button because you immediately turn it off. That is addressed in @rjuzzle’s answer. Or maybe something else is wrong. You have not given any details so we can only guess.

Comment: See rjuzzle's answer. Your code will only set the LED pin to high for less than a millisecond on each pass through your loop when the button is pressed - the flickering will be so short that you probably won't be able to see it.

Comment: Your question needs work. See [how to ask](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

In this example your missing a semi-colin after `int buttonPin = 2`, and your if statement should probably look like this

```
if (buttonValue == HIGH){
  digitalWrite(lightpin, HIGH);
}//red

else{
  digitalWrite(lightpin, LOW);//red
}//red/*
```

Also if you go into the examples in the Arduino IDE, under "digital", this sketch is called button.

Comment: Assuming the problem is that the LED doesn't appear to light at all, the answer is moving the code that turns the LED off to the else clause as you have shown in your answer. Otherwise the LED will only be lit for less than a millisecond - probably such a short time that it wouldn't be visible to the human eye.